# ArangoDB Synchronizing System Collections

Tags: database, replication, arangodb

I recently reformatted my comp and now I'm setting up my dev environment again, which includes ArangoDB. I'm synchronizing data from our production db into my dev db for testing. This works fine except it doesn't sync the system collections, specifically the _users collection. Is this possible to do, or will I have to recreate the users manually in my dev environment?

I tried using the restrictType and restrictCollections arguments, but I must be doing something wrong because it returns:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "errorMessage": "invalid value for <restrictCollections> or <restrictType>",
    "code": 400,
    "errorNum": 400
}
```

I'm submitting this: (my actual data replaced for obvious security reasons)

```
{
    "endpoint": "tcp://myserver.com:8529",
    "database": "mydb",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "restrictType":"include",
    "restrictCollections":"_users"
}
```

It works without the restrictType and restrictCollections keys. I think I have the syntax wrong. Any ideas? thanks!

UPDATE: My syntax was wrong, I corrected it below, but unfortunately it still won't sync system databases. Is there a way to do this, or a better option? Thanks!

```
{
    "endpoint": "tcp://myserver.com:8529",
    "database": "mydb",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "restrictType":"include",
    "restrictCollections":["_users"] //takes an array, not a list of strings
}
```

Comment: The `_users` collection is currently always excluded from replication, regardless of how the replication is configured. 
This is to ensure that master and slaves can have different users or credentials.

Comment: I think it would be better if `_users` could optionally be replicated, too. Whether or not should depend on some configuration variable. I'll check if I can work on this.

Comment: That would be great! Meanwhile, I used the "download JSON" option on the _users collection and uploaded to the _users collection on my dev box and it worked fine. However, I think it would be cool to optionally include any system collections in replication. This would be handy for performing a complete offsite backup.

Comment: I have implemented inclusion or exclusion of collections for the replication for `devel`: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/909b1300bd119af808ad3d6696617d824abc7c4f

Comment: Great! if I run this dev build on my laptop, but keep the stable build on our server, will I be able to replicate system collections? Or will I need the dev build in both places? Also, when do you expect this feature will show up in a stable release? Version 2.3.2?

Comment: 2.3 will still exclude some collections from replication. That means if your master is still on 2.3, it will use the "old" code and exclude the `_users` collection. The code is currently checked in for devel, which will become 2.4 eventually. The release is planned for the end of this month currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @stj there is an implemented `inclusion` and `exclusion` of system  collections for the replication in our `devel` branch: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/909b1300bd119af808ad3d6696617d824abc7c4f

This should also be in the 2.4 release which is planned for the end of the year.